# After installing react-native-screens app getting crash

Tags: react-native, crash, react-navigation-v5

After installing `react-native-screens` my app getting crash on building time.

When I installed  `react-navigation` 5.x. It build successfully but unable to load in emulator. It’s getting crash every  time. But when i uninstall `react-native-screens` it's worked but without `react-native-screens` i couldn't use `react-navigation` features.

package.json

```
{
  "name": "Khulna",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.7",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.1.1",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^5.1.1",
    "@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs": "^5.1.1",
    "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "^5.1.1",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.0.9",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.1.1",
    "react": "16.9.0",
    "react-native": "0.61.5",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.6.0",
    "react-native-paper": "^3.6.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.7.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^0.7.3",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.2.0",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^2.13.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.6.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.6.2",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.6.2",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^0.0.5",
    "babel-jest": "^24.9.0",
    "eslint": "^6.5.1",
    "jest": "^24.9.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.56.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.9.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

android\app\build.gradle

```
dependencies {

    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-rc01"
    implementation "androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.1.0-alpha02"

    if (enableHermes) {
        def hermesPath = "../../node_modules/hermes-engine/android/";
        debugImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-debug.aar")
        releaseImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-release.aar")
    } else {
        implementation jscFlavor
    }
}
```

index.js

```
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import App from './App';
import {name as appName} from './app.json';

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
```

Comment: Share your App.js file

Comment: i have nothing add to my app.js file. it is default app.js.@Parth shrivastav

Comment: Is this a new React Native app? Which version? Does it crash on iOS or Android?

Comment: Yes. This is a new React Native app. Version: 0.61. i'm using windows machine. it crash on Android. @PetrBela

Comment: Can you just follow up on the docs over [here(react-navigation v5)](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started/) ? And make the changes as suggested there.

Comment: i follow official docs of react-navigation that you given.@Parthshrivastav